# Javascript Regular Expression for NetBios

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need Javascript Regular Expression for NetBios, Which need to fulfill following criteria:
**Allowed characters**

NetBIOS computer names can contain all alphanumeric characters except for the extended characters that are listed in the "Disallowed characters" section. Names can contain a period, but names cannot start with a period.

**Disallowed characters**

NetBIOS computer names cannot contain the following characters:

backslash ()
slash mark (/)
colon (:)
asterisk (*)
question mark (?)
quotation mark (")
less than sign (<)
greater than sign (>)
vertical bar (|)
.

**Minimum name length**
1 character.

**Maximum name length**
15 characters.

Note The 16th character is reserved to identify the functionality that is installed on the registered network device.

Comment: Partially it is resolved RegEx is /^(?!^[\W_]|[W_]$)[a-zA-z0-9._-][^"/\\\[\]:|*?<>]{0,14}$/igm Now the problem is its not allowing all special character at start.

Answer (score 0):

That one should do it:

```
^(?!\.)(?![0-9]{1,15}$)[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,15}$
```

(?![0-9]{1,15}$) - non entirely numeric

(?!.) - can not start with a period

[a-zA-Z0-9-_.] - allowed chars

{1,15} - from 1 up to 15 chars